# Ruby on Rails ganerate Json

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I have a controller that generates a Json. I use that Json to show records in a Google Maps, but I wnat to show only those has the param `toll=="true"`, and those who do not have, will not be displayed.

I'm thinking of doing this filter directly in Json (through the url generated), and when I call this through javascript, I call the url with the parameter I need. How can I access through url only those has the param `toll=="true"`? example: `localhost:3000/map_pis?tool=="true"`?:

```
class PointOfInterestsController < ApplicationController
  def map
    pis = PointOfInterest.all
    fares = FareCity.all
    msg = '
      {
        "pis": [
          '
    total_pis = ''
    pis.each do |p|
      total_pis += '
     {"kilometer": ' + p.kilometer.to_s + ',
      "category": "pis",
      "name": "' + p.name + '",
      "show_on_map": "' + p.point_of_interest_category.show_on_map.to_s + '",
      "lat": ' + p.lat.to_s + ',
      "lng": ' + p.lng.to_s + ',
      "icon": "' + p.point_of_interest_category.icon.url + '",
      "description": "' + p.description + '",
      "image": "' + p.image.url + '"},'
    end

    fares.each do |f|
      total_pis += '
     {"kilometer": ' + f.kilometer.to_s + ',
      "category": "fare",
      "name": "' + f.name + '",
      "toll": "' + f.is_toll.to_s + '",
      "lat": ' + f.lat.to_s + ',
      "lng": ' + f.lng.to_s + ',
      "icon": "/img/icon_fare_map.png",
        "pedagios": ['
    total_fares = ''

    f.fare_pricings.each do |fp|
      total_fares += '
      {"title": "' + fp.fare_category.title.to_s + '",
      "price": ' + fp.price.to_s + '},'
    end

    total_pis += total_fares[0...-1]

    total_pis += '] },'
    end

    msg += total_pis[0...-1]

    msg +='
        ]
      }
    '
    render :json => msg
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really the right way to generate JSON in Rails. You should be simply doing something like `msg = fares.as_json(include: ...)`, where `include` is the list of fields you want. Your whole controller action should only be a few lines long. It's *never* a good idea to manually build a string containing JSON this way, at the very least you should be building a Ruby hash and then calling `render json: my_hash` and letting Rails produce valid JSON for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you call `toll=="true"` refers to the attribute `is_toll`(true/false) of your `FareCity` model, you can make the conditional display directly inside the controller:

```
def map
  pis = PointOfInterest.all
  fares = FareCity.where(is_toll: true)
  #...
end
```

As it says, only the fares where `is_toll` is true will be render in the json.

Comment: Man, I don't believe it was so simple and I did not think about it. Thank you very much. Now it's working just the way I need it.